# Loop Iteration Analysis

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

See solution below, I would like some constructive feedback.

what is the running time in O(n) below.

```
int a = 0;
int k = n*n*n; //n^3
while(k > 1) 
{
  for (int j=0; j<k; j++) //runs from 0->k
  { a--; }
k = k/2; //divides by 2 each iteration
}
```

each time the for loop runs, it gives a constant x k.

= 0xn^3 + 1x (n^3/2) + 2x(n^3/4) +...+ nx(n^3/2^n)
= n^3 (0 + 1/2 + 2/4 +...+ n/2^n) <- anyone know how I can simplify this down further?

Edit: i am assuming we would use the arithmetic series somehow....

Comment: Your reasoning is flawed: the sequence isn't 0xn^3 + 1x(n^3/2) + 2x(n^3/4) + ..., but rather is 1xn^3 + 1x(n^3/2) + 1x(n^3/4) + ... = n^3 x (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...) = 2xn^3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use k first

in first while loop, the for loop runs k times

in second while loop, the for loop runs k/2 times

in third while loop, the for loop runs k/4 times

...

so in total it runs ( k + k/2 + k/4 + k/8 + ... + 1) times

after extract the k, it's k * ( 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/k)

as k increases, the part in parentheses becomes 2, which we can ignore

change k to n^3, the result is O(n^3)

Comment: it seems you're not really taking into account the nested for loop?
why are you multiplying ( 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/k) by-> k?

Comment: ok silly arithmetic mistake but that still doesn't explain that you're not taking into account the nested for loop right? so for each value 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/k you have to take into account the for loop run time aswell. ( which it seems like you have not done) ... correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @warpstar in each while loop, i'm counting how many times the for loop iterates, see my 2nd to 4th line

Answer (score 0):

I think you can come up with the order of growth complexity via the following formal equation below:

[image]